# disabling basic auth on certain endpoints in nginx conf file does not work

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, basic-authentication, amazon-elb

I am attempting to disable basic authentication for certain endpoints on my website, as some third-party services send requests to the site.

I have two EC2 instances and an Application Load Balancer (ALB) behind them. This is my nginx configuration file. As you can see, I have enabled authentication in the server block and disabled it for certain endpoints. However, when I try to access certain endpoints, such as https://website.domain/api/providers/bgaming/rollback, I am still prompted to enter a username and password, when I should not be.

```
upstream fpm_backend {
    server unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;

    keepalive 256;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;

    root /home/xxxx/xxxx/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    charset utf-8;

    error_page 404 /index.php;
    
    auth_basic "Restricted access";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /api/provider/aleaplay/callback/transactions {
        auth_basic off;
    }
    location /api/provider/aleaplay/callback/players/ {
        auth_basic off;
    }
    location /callback {
        auth_basic off;
    }
    location /api/providers/bgaming/play {
        auth_basic off;
    }
    location /api/providers/bgaming/rollback {
        auth_basic off;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /web.config {
        return 404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass fpm_backend;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    client_max_body_size 20M;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your configuration, everything ends up being handled by the root `index.php` file. The `/index.php` URI is handled by the `location ~ \.php$` block and requires authentication.

To disable authentication for `/api/providers/bgaming/rollback`, you will need to use `auth_basic off` **and** handle the entire request within the same location block.

For example:

```
location ^~ /api/providers/bgaming/rollback {
    auth_basic off;

    try_files /index.php =404;

    fastcgi_pass fpm_backend;
    include fastcgi_params;
 }
```

The `^~` operator causes this location to [take precedence](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) (which is probably not required in this particular case). The `try_files` statement changes the request to `index.php` but as it is **not** the [last parameter](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files), the request continues to be handled within the same location block. The final two statements processes the request as a PHP file.